# How do I use Quicktype Json C# generated classes to Deserialize a JSON file

Tags: c#, json, windows, quicktype

I have a very large Json file (cannot share)
Im using https://quicktype.io/csharp/ to generate a C# class from this json file

It gives me a class that looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace QuickType
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    using System.Globalization;
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;

    public partial class Tem
    {
        [JsonProperty("Cal")]
        public Cal Cal_ { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Cal
    {
        [JsonProperty("Cam")]
        public Camera[] Cam_ { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Dis")]
        public Dis[] Dis_ { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Eye")]
        public Eye[] Eye_ { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Ine")]
        public Ine[] Ine_ { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Metadata")]
        public Metadata Metadata_ { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Tem")]
        public Tem Tem_ { get; set; }
    }
    //...There are a lot more
}
```

Then it has some built internal classes

```
internal static class Converter
{
    public static readonly JsonSerializerSettings Settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore,
        DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None,
        Converters =
        {
            ShutterConverter.Singleton,
            AssignedEyeConverter.Singleton,
            LocationConverter.Singleton,
            new IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeStyles = DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal }
        },
    };
}
```

Not sure what to do with these

I tried to deserialize it this way but it didn't work, all the values were null

```
 using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(file path))
 {
         string json = r.ReadToEnd();

         QuickType.Cal test = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<QuickType.Cal>(json);

 }
```

I know that the file path is correct and the json string contains the json file. But I dont know how Im supposed to convert from Json.net to this Json generated class

Thanks,

Comment: Does Json2csharp.com work?

Comment: That didn't help. Im still getting Null for all the data in the class

Answer (score 1):

As suggested above by Jeremy Thompson I switched to Json2csharp.com because the formatting is much simpler

Then I parse with `Cal.RootObject test = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Cal.RootObject>(json);`